# How to get all column names without one column in sql table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to get all column names without one column in sql table in  SQL Server.

I have a temp table. It has columns:

```
ID, Status, Code, Name, Location, Address, Title, Category, Line, date, time, UserName
```

I want all data without the `id` column

I want an alternative to this SQL code for this

```
SELECT Status, Code, Name, Location, Address, Title, Category, Line, date, time, UserName 
FROM TEMP
```

Comment: You cannot do this; if you want only some columns from a table, you must list them all. No way around this.

Comment: You can do this only if you are building dynamic SQL statement and using sp_executesql.

Comment: +1 for balancing inappropriate negative votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below query to select all column data without a column. Variable `@ColList` gives the column names except column `ID`:

```
DECLARE @ColList nvarchar(4000), @SQLStatment nvarchar(4000),@myval nvarchar(30)
SET @ColList = ''

select @ColList = @ColList + Name + ' , ' from syscolumns where id = object_id('TableName') AND Name != 'ID'
SELECT @SQLStatment = 'SELECT ' + Substring(@ColList,1,len(@ColList)-1) + ' From TableName'

EXEC(@SQLStatment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no "SELECT Everything except some columns" in SQL. You have to list out the ones you need.

If this is a temp table I guess you could try to drop the ID column before selecting the result. This is not appropriate if you need it again though...

```
ALTER TABLE Temp DROP COLUMN Id

Then

SELECT * FROM Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

You can't define wildcards in column names or select all but some. You have to name the ones you want to select or use `*` to select all.